# Faster way to add multiple markers on Google Maps v3 Javascript

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add a lot of markers into **Google Map**. I'm already passing the data to the server to make clusters on "busy" areas to help keep the number of markers down.

Here is my code:

```
        markers.forEach(function(item, i){

            if (item.count) {

                // this is a cluster one, so add the respective icon along with the number as a label

                // check we have a value for this. If we don't it means that someone has 2 markers with the exact same lat/lng, so lets ignore it!
                if (item.coordinate) {

                    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(item.coordinate[0], item.coordinate[1]); // lat,lng of cluster

                    var cluster_icon;
                    if (item.count < 10) {
                        cluster_icon = icon_markers_1;
                    } else if (item.count < 30) {
                        cluster_icon = icon_markers_2; //
                    } else if (item.count < 50) {
                        cluster_icon = icon_markers_3; //
                    } else if (item.count < 100) {
                        cluster_icon = icon_markers_4; //
                    } else {
                        cluster_icon = icon_markers_5; //
                    }


                    window.VARS.markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                              position: location,
                              //label: String(item.count),
                              title: "lat:"+item.coordinate[0]+ ",lng: " + item.coordinate[1],
                              label: {
                                text: String(item.count),
                                color: "#fff",
                                fontSize: "16px",
                                fontWeight: "bold"
                              },
                              map: window.VARS.Google_Map_Modal,
                              icon: cluster_icon
                    });

                    window.VARS.markers[i].addListener('click', function() {
                        //console.dir(window.VARS.markers[i].getPosition().lat());
                        var zoom = window.VARS.Google_Map_Modal.getZoom();
                        zoom++;
                        if (zoom <= 20) {
                            window.VARS.Google_Map_Modal.setZoom(zoom++)
                        }

                        window.VARS.Google_Map_Modal.setCenter(this.getPosition());
                    });
                }

            } else {


                var link = window.VARS.links_stored[item.link_id];

                // this is an actual marker (not cluster), so lets add it to the map
                var location = new google.maps.LatLng(link.latitude, link.longitude); // lat,lng of cluster

                var dataPhoto = link.image_small;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    title: link.title,
                    the_row: i,
                    linkid: link.linkid,
                    map: window.VARS.Google_Map_Modal
                });

                window.VARS.markers.push(marker);
                window.VARS.marker_vals.push(item);
                //bounds.extend(latLng);

                marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    // do some stuff
                });



            }
        });
```

Is there a better way to do this, rather than one by one? I read that you could "batch add" to the map - but I can't seem to find any documentation to support this.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of re-inventing the wheel by implementing a custom clustering logic, you can use the one provided by Google Maps.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

Adding markers one by one makes the map incredibly slow. MarkerClusterer avoids this issue by creating an array of markers but not adding them to the map.

The markers are added together at the end when you initialize the MarkerClusterer by passing the marker array.

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
        {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
```

This is extremely quick and efficient, allowing addition of thousands of markers without too much of a performance hit.

Comment: we already used that and it was painfully slow on larger data sets. Thus moving to a server based one. The frustrating part is that their demo IS fast for the client based one, but just not for us. I think it partly has to do with the size of the map being shown (1600x900px on some browsers)

Comment: here is what I mean. This is a video of the cluster stuff running on the site: https://vimeo.com/294528105 . Thats not usable by users. Even as the dev it was annoying me at how slow it was (and users will be even more fussy)

Comment: Maybe you should ask yourself why it is so slow with your code, when you saw examples of it that are much faster. How many markers are you adding? How were you adding them when it was that slow? etc.

Comment: @AndrewNewby - I had faced a similar issue with larger data sets. One mistake I realized I was making was adding `map: map` property while creating the markers. Adding the map property causes each marker to get added to the map instead of getting added just once as is the case with MarkerClusterer. If you check the example on the link you'll notice that they set only the position and label. That was something that I had missed during implementation.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I have literally trimmed the script down the bare minimum and its still painfully slow. The tiles take ages to load (the clustering isn't too bad, but the tile download speed is unbearable). I'm now looking into Leaflet using OSM as this seems like a better option and a LOT quicker in comparison.

Comment: IDK. If, as you said, you trimmed your code to the bare minimums and still have issues, then post it here and someone might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: @MrUpsidown thanks but I don't think there is anything that can be done. I've literally cut it back to just a simple `new google.maps.Map()` and having it 100% height and 100% width (done with flex). Then you zoom in, and it takes 2 seconds to reload the tiles. I'm running it in a 1900x920px browser window, so its quite large but not ridiculous. FKI I'm testing by not even including the markers and its still super laggy

Comment: But then the issue must be somewhere else... Your browser? Your Internet connection? Did you ever test your code on another computer, or online, and with another connection? I can load a much bigger Google Maps instance with many markers and it won't show any lag.

Comment: @MrUpsidown mmm interesting. It does seem quite a bit worse in FF. Chrome is the fastest, and Edge isn't too bad (still not great though). It won't be my internet as I'm on a 80mbps and download huge files in minutes.

Comment: @MrUpsidown also as I mentioned, I did test it without any markers at all. The tile loading was just almost as bad (taking 5+ seconds to reload them before it was usable)

Comment: @AndrewNewby - Your slowness issue seems to be more with loading google maps itself rather than due to loading large data sets of markers.

Comment: @Joyson it does seem so now that I've taken the markers out. Either way its not usable so it looks like I don't have a choice but to move to another system :( Its a shame, as I'm quite used to work with Google Maps JS so its going to be a PITA to convert the new site to use that instead. However, at the end of the day the UX is the most important and its just not usable as is :(

Comment: FWIW I've been playing with Leaflet JS and Leaflet MarkerCluster and the difference in speed is ridiculous (even in FF). I'm wishing I'd played around with it earlier instead of trying to get Google Maps working to an acceptable level :(

Comment: Leaflet JS is really good and fast. The major disadvantage is that it lacks the same level of details as google maps.

Comment: @Joyson yeah for sure. but TBH thats fine for what our users need (they only need to see where the hotels are). I *love*  the clustering module too - much nicer! I'm just trying to get my head around the difference in logic with it now though (for example looping over markers that are on the map - as well as those included in the clusters)